# Community Building: Topic challenge ideas thread

Tags: discussion, challenge

Jon Ericson recently posted a [Meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) about how boost the amount of questions on the site, and promote activity in topics that may otherwise receive only a small amount of attention. I've seen it utilized[<sup>1</sup>](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-needs-more-challenge-topics) on other[<sup>2</sup>](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/weekly-topic-challenge) sites[<sup>3</sup>](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/weekly-topic-challenge) and it seems[<sup>4</sup>](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge) to do fairly well. Here's how it works:

- If you have an idea for a topic, add it as an answer below. Please use one topic per answer.
- Next week, I or a volunteer (henceforth known as **"the organizer"**) selects one of the topics (highest voted) and writes up a new meta post introducing the challenge for the week. The topic will be associated with a specific tag or tag set so that we can count how many questions were asked.
- Anyone who wants to participate simply has to asks about the topic of the week and tag it with the appropriate tag.
- At the end of the challenge, the organizer posts an answer to the challenge with a count of how many questions were asked and anything else they feel like highlighting.
- The organizer picks a new topic and starts back on the second bullet.

Note: It's fine to ask a question you know the answer to, and **posting your own question/answer is good**.

You can add topics to this list at any time, and if(when) we run out, this challenge series ends.

Comment: It might be an interesting twist to make some of the topics more like a game based on votes (i.e. overcoming an obstacle with a user) so people become competitive and want to compete (people are *really* competitive) to get more attention. Best if we could make it fun and add great content to our site :)

Answer (score 9):

[**COMPLETED**](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/190/78)

Non-digital communities.

We've said we support non-digital communities, but we have no questions. Let's start a series of questions related to this aspect of our site.

One example of a more focused "non-digital communities" theme is questions related to your neighborhood. Any community defined primarily by geographic area or physical proximity might qualify as a neighborhood. The term typically implies a residential area but could also refer to: stores in a particular section of a shopping mall; suites in an industrial complex housing different businesses/teams; people who work near each other in an office building; etc.

Another example is committees, clubs, etc.  These might have officers who are in charge of aspects of the organization, or they might be consensus-driven organizations where all members have the same status and privileges.

---

*Chosen for the [inaugural challenge](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/83).*

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but can we focus it more? "Non-digital communities" is pretty broad and we have no examples to seed that niche.

Comment: Sure. I wanted to start broad to get creative juices flowing. I'll think about how it can be narrowed it down.

Answer (score 6):

[**COMPLETED**](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/213/78)

[new-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-users) has many questions about how to encourage a new user to conform to site policies. I think we can expand this tag to include questions about engaging new users, encouraging them to stick around, and not hammering them over the head with rules.

Answer (score 5):

[**COMPLETED**](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1276/78)

Let's ask questions about *transitions*.  No community is static; communities grow and shrink, become more or less active, etc.  How do we keep them functional when this happens?  How do we add some structure to a community that's now too large to run by consensus?  How do we migrate a community from one platform to another?  (That's not a technical question but a community one.)  How do we respond to shrinking -- or even dying -- communities?

This isn't a tag but a general idea.  We've had a couple questions in this space; I suspect there are more to be asked yet.

Answer (score 4):

We might get some mileage out of questions about working with short-term/temporary communities. Anything from a one-day training, workshop or hackathon, to a several-months long cohort of classmates or co-workers.

I think these questions would tend to favor offline communities but by no means exclude online communities – MOOCs, kickstarter backers, etc.